# Sorting data in file in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python, and I was curious as to how I would sort a data file and store the items in the file properly. Here is an example of what the data file looks like.

> item1 0.0 1.0
>
> item2 2.0 2.0
>
> item2 1.5 2.0
>
> item1 2.6 1.2

I want to take all of item1's and all of item2's and group them together separately and also keep track of each item's two values. I made a class to store this data.

```
class myClass:
   item_name = " "
   x_val = 0.0
   y_val = 0.0
```

I've gotten started a bit

```
with open(fname, "r") as f:
    content = f.readlines()
```

but I can't quite wrap my head around how to use those lines to build my class.

How can I read this data from the file and store the information appropriately?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far and where you're running into problems?

Comment: All i have tried is `with open(fname) as f: content = f.readlines()`. I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to take those read lines and store them as an instance of myClass.

Comment: I'd suggest that before attempting this, you go through some tutorials on using python objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
class myClass(object):

    def __init__(self, name, x, y):
        self.name = name
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

item1 = []
item2 = []
filename = "some_file.txt"

with open(filename, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        a = line.split()
        name, x, y = a[0], a[1], a[2]
        if name == "item1":
            item1.append(myClass(name, x, y))
        elif name == "item2":
            item2.append(myClass(name, x, y))
        else:
            raise ValueError("Item is improperly named")
```

In order to use the class effectively you need a constructor (the `__init__()` method).  This lets you pass arguments to the class and store them as instance variables (`name`, `x` and `y`).  Then you iterate through each line of the file, split the line (based on spaces) and then add the instance of `myClass` to the appropriate list